# cannot use eBPF __kptr_ref feature

Tags: ebpf, bpf

6.1.0-1004-oem Ubuntu 22.04
I study the __kptr_ref feature of ebpf.
To understand it, I made a filter.
But I cannot use this feature for verifier :(

bpf filter source code is the below.

```c
...
struct my_ref {
    struct my __kptr_ref *my;
};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, struct my_ref);
    __uint(max_entries, 16);
} arr SEC(".maps");

SEC("lsm/cred_prepare")
int handle_cred_prepare (struct cred *new, const struct cred *old, gfp_t gfp, int ret)
{
    struct my_ref *val;
    int key = 0;
    val = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&arr, &(int){0} );
    if (!val)
        return 0;

    bpf_kptr_xchg(&val->my, NULL);
    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

And verifier give me the error.

```
map 'arr' has no valid kptr
processed 11 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'handle_cred_prepare': failed to load: -13
libbpf: failed to load object 'hello_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'hello_bpf': -13
failed to load BPF object -13`
```

I runtime debug the kernel and find the function fails at btf_find_kptr
(I find the place roughly.)

```c
static int btf_find_kptr(const struct btf *btf, const struct btf_type *t,
             u32 off, int sz, struct btf_field_info *info)
{
    enum bpf_kptr_type type;
    u32 res_id;

    /* For PTR, sz is always == 8 */
    if (!btf_type_is_ptr(t))
        return BTF_FIELD_IGNORE;
    // may be here is the error point
    t = btf_type_by_id(btf, t->type); 
    // or here is the error point..
    if (!btf_type_is_type_tag(t))
        return BTF_FIELD_IGNORE;
    /* Reject extra tags */
    if (btf_type_is_type_tag(btf_type_by_id(btf, t->type)))
        return -EINVAL;
    if (!strcmp("kptr", __btf_name_by_offset(btf, t->name_off)))
        type = BPF_KPTR_UNREF;
    else if (!strcmp("kptr_ref", __btf_name_by_offset(btf, t->name_off)))
        type = BPF_KPTR_REF;
    else
        return -EINVAL;

    /* Get the base type */
    t = btf_type_skip_modifiers(btf, t->type, &res_id);
    /* Only pointer to struct is allowed */
    if (!__btf_type_is_struct(t))
        return -EINVAL;

    info->type_id = res_id;
    info->off = off;
    info->type = type;
    return BTF_FIELD_FOUND;
}
```

May I miss some point?

Comment: Could you share an example that can be loaded and reproduced, with the loader code? Did you check if the BTF was correctly loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the `__kptr` annotation when compiling the bpf object with **clang-14**.
By inspecting the BTF with `bpftool btf dump file <obj>` I couldn't locate any `'kptr'` `TYPE_TAG`.
Updating to **clang-15** solved the problem.
It seems **clang-14** is not emitting the tag.